# Popup Javascript blocked with registerClientScriptBlock

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup, window.open, registerclientscriptblock

I'm trying to open a popup at server-side but it seems only work with IE, other browsers block the opening of it.
If i call the javascript function directly on the client-side it works well with all browsers, but i need to call it at server-side with RegisterClientScriptBlock.
Any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "newpage", "wopen('" + url + "');", true);
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    function wopen(url) {
        var w = window.open(url, '', 'width=1000,height=600,toolbar=0,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,directories=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');
        w.focus();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you tried to utilize RegisterStartupStript method instead?

Comment: This code act as a typical behaviour of unwanted - popups. Thats why they are blocked by the browsers (considered as unwanted-popups). Clients can allow the pop-up then they can see your new page.